# Apartir de un segundo select llenar un textbox

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este esl el codigo, necesito que apartir de un segundo select se llene un text textbox.

Comment: Te recomendamos agregar el codigo y no una foto. Saludos.

Comment: Eso lo puedes trabajar con AJAX, no creo que haya otra forma. Saludos

Comment: capturando el evento onchange con js, lo puedes consguir sin necesidad de ajax, pero lo ideal es que uses ajax es mas eficiente y rapido

Comment: Creo que tu problema es similar a este, revisa esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68842/autocompletar-campos-input-a-partir-de-una-selecci%c3%b3n-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola no me deja comentar, pero por lo visto tenes que pasarle al textbox el valor con `tutextbox.innerText=select.value` que es una propiedad. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp 
espero que te sirva.
Saludos

Comment: Ahora si podéis comentar ;) de nada.

Comment: Que grandee!! @JorgeLuisAlcantara

Comment: te recomiendo que le agregues código, es para cuando los enlaces caigan haya un respaldo aquí y ademas sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad, sino te van poner punto negativo. ;)

Comment: De acuerdo, ahorita subo el codigo. Soy nuevo en esta pagina. Gracias por el apoyo, en un momento reviso.